# Best solution for a shared addressbook with family?

Tags: address-book

I'm looking for a good solution for keeping a shared addressbook for my wife and me. Rather than each of us having our own copy of family and friends' contacts, I'd like us both to be accessing a shared database that stores email addresses, phone numbers, postal addresses, birthdays, anniversaries, etc.

I suppose I'm looking for a lite CRM tool, right? Has anyone else got a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps lets you share contacts, calendars, and documents within your domain.  You could also set up a starting page using Google sites.

The [Standard Edition](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) is free.

Even though Google Apps is geared toward business and enterprise I think it is great for family.  We use it to keep track of the kids school and sports schedules and my sons also use docs for all their school projects and papers.

It does require you to have a [domain name](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new) and you can purchase one through Google for $10 a year.

Comment: From my reading you can't have shared addressbooks unless you start paying google. (With the free account it only shares contacts in the domain.) Is that correct?

Comment: I am using the free version and I only had to enable shared contacts in my domain management dashboard.  When you enable contacts you will have a link to the shared address book that can be accessed by any of your members.

Comment: That's interesting -- my wife and I have been using Google Apps for our domain for a couple of years. I've enabled contact sharing, and when I search for contacts I can see hers under "other contacts". When she searches my contacts don't show up in her results. It would be an okay solution if it worked, except we can't edit each others contacts.